# $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^{-n}$ \ injectivity

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read a proof, where on a side note it was stated that $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^{-n}=a_0+\frac{a_1}{z}+…$ is injective on the punctured unit disc $D^{\times}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | 0 < |z| <1\}$.
However it is not clear for me that g(z) would be injective there, how could one show that?

The proof that I meant can be found here when scrolling down
https://www.math3ma.com/blog/automorphisms-of-the-complex-plane

Comment: Without any assumption concerning the $a_n$'s?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: not that I know of, that was the weird part, but I have posted the link to the proof.

Comment: Since $f$ in injective and so is $z\mapsto\frac1z$, if you define $g(z)=f\left(\frac1z\right)$, then $g$ is injective too. Done.

Comment: There is indeed an assumption on the $a_n$'s, namely that $\sum a_n z$ is a power series for $f$ (which is an automorphism of $\mathbb C$). This assumption is important. Also note $f$ is injective since we are assuming it is an automorphism. That is what makes it work.

Comment: In the proof you linked, it is assumed that $f(z)$ is injective, which implies that $g(z) = f(1/z)$ is injective on the punctured disk, since $f(1/z_1) = f(1/z_2)$ implies $1/z_1 = 1/z_2$ and hence $z_1 = z_2$,

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: thank you

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: thank you for your explanation